# Geocoder failed due to: ZERO_RESULTS error in google map reverse geocoding example

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am testing the reverse geocoding example given on the [site](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)

I am testing various values for indian cities like delhi, mumbai. Its running fine.

But when i pass the latitude and longitude of jammu and kashmir i.e `32.491249204776416, 74.92896563110344`. It shows `Geocoder failed due to: ZERO_RESULTS`

I failed to understand the reason for such a weird behavior.

Comment: Does Google Maps support geocoding outside the US? Maybe you need to specify the 'region' parameter - see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Hi tofarr thanks for replying. I am sure that google maps support geocoding outside the us because its working fine for other indian cities like delhi,punjab etc. I have also tried the region parameter but same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though Google maps geo-coding supports areas outside US, there are few locations which are not supported by Google maps.

Few areas in Jammu&Kashmir as you mentioned in your question and few locations in Israel are not supported. (Also sometimes for locations that contain special characters, this error is thrown).

There is nothing much you can do. All you can do is handle the error in your code :)